# Are the outputs of /proc/meminfo, /proc/cpuinfo etc always in English?

Tags: linux, kernel, locale, i18n

I am writing code that relies on the output of /proc/meminfo, /proc/cpuinfo etc. Are the file contents always in English? For example, will `MemTotal` in /proc/meminfo always be `MemTotal` in all locales?

Comment: I cannot provide you with conclusive evidence, but since `/proc` is an interface that is intended to be used programmatically (there are no alternative system calls, etc -- this is the *only* place to get certain information, and lots of applications use it), it seems completely inconceivable for it to be any other way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, usually that is the case, as those messages are provided by the kernel itself, and including a hundred translations into the kernel image itself would serve no purpose other than increasing the kernel size dramatically.

For many things there are front-ends, user space programs which read the kernel info and present it in a translated fashion.

Answer (score 3):

`proc virtual filesystem` has two part:

```
1. /proc/[PID]/blahblah
2. /proc/* #versus of no.1 such as cpuinfo meminfo partitions and so on.
```

May be you will be see another locale in content of `/proc/[PID]/files` , because some of them such as `environ` fill up by user, so may be you can see another locale.But in part no2 or some of part no1 never you don't see another loccale.Also they aren't translatable.